# How ManagedBeans figure out to which facelet or xhtml file they belong?

Tags: jsf, facelets, managed-bean

In JSF, I wonder how a ManagedBean understands that it should be available to an xhtml or facelet ?

Comment: @BalusC you are right. I actually meant how do they find each other, now I have to say how an xhtml file containing form understands it it should give it's submitted values t to one of the ManagedBeans among the rest.

Comment: @BalusC could you please vote up this question because they have banned me from questioning thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind component values and objects to managed bean properties or to reference managed bean methods from component tags, page authors should use the Expression Language syntax. 
When user make request to the page that contains EL, that refers to specific manage bean, this bean will be instantiated by JSF framework (except managed beans that have attribute eager="true", that means that managed bean is created before it is requested for the first time). 
So the fact is that managed bean will be instantiated by JSF container and works as a model for the appropriate UI Component so the Facelet will know about the Bean, not vice versa

Comment: but how does jsf knows which managed bean it should instantiate ?

Comment: You usually register your managed bean using Xml configuration

or
by using annotations (available from JSF 2.0):
`@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld", eager = true)
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorld {
   ...
}`

.When #{helloWorld} bean will be reffered from the facelet, JSF container will do something like this:

`FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Bean bean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{helloWorld}", Bean.class);`

Comment: I am following a tutorial that has none of what you metioned and it still works, https://blog.udemy.com/jsf-tutorial-an-introduction-to-jsf/#7

Comment: In your tutorial you register the bean with the annotation @ManagedBean. JSF container initializes  managed beans during the runtime "behind the scenes"

Comment: but how does it know it should use Student Managed beans and nothing else ?

Comment: Facelet gets it from the FacesContext, by key "Student". If bean was already created it gets the bean by key.   FacesContext stores the managed beans as Map values. Key - bean's name, value - bean's instance.

Comment: what if I had another Student.java in another package ?

Comment: If the bean classes have the same class name, then it's already a poor design from the beginning on. Ask yourself, why do they have the same class name? Do they have the same responsibilities? Why not just make it one class? Or do they have different responsibilities? Give the classes a different name.
Your IDE will create warnings and runtime the container will сreate them too

Comment: so there is no way to say that this xhtml file should use this ManagedBean ?

Comment: kalym4ik could you please vote up this question because they have banned me from questioning thank you.